# Updating window object per test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I have some conditional logic in a component that reads window.location.pathname.
To test this I want to shallow render a component without touching the window, asserting, then shallow rendering again but this time with a different window.location.pathname and assert.

It seems like after the first shallow render enzyme locks the window object for all following renders. Ignoring any changes I make to the window object in the current process.

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  describe('render', () => {
    it('default render', () => {
      const component = <SomeComponent><div>test</div></SomeComponent>;
      const wrapper = shallow(component);
      expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });

  describe('lifecycle', () => {
    describe('componentDidMount', () => {
      it('calls Foo.bar with the locations pathname', () => {
        const pathname = '/test';
        Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'pathname', {
          writable: true,
          value: pathname,
        });
        const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />);
        expect(Foo.bar.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(pathname);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

So the second test works when run by itself. But when that first test runs then the second test fails. Apparently enzyme doesn't let you update the window between test.
Is this true or am I missing something. If it is true then what would be an alternative to test this?

Thanks